# Can a parent read from a pipe if a child dies?

Tags: c, pipe

If a parent and child process communicate via a pipe, what would happen if a parent reads from a pipe after a child process has written to it and died?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the child dies, its end of the pipe is automatically closed. The parent will read EOF after reading everything that the child wrote before it died, just as if the client called `close()` explicitly.

Note that the parent can only read data that has actually been written to the pipe. If the child process is performing buffered output, as is the default when using `stdio`, all the data the application has written might not be in the pipe when it dies. Stdio buffers are automatically flushed when the process calls `exit()`, but if it dies due to a signal this will not be called.

Comment: Buffered data could be in some layer writing to the pipe (e.g., C’s stdio services) rather than in the pipe itself, and that data would be lost when the child dies.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But then, technically, the process has not written it to the pipe yet

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ctx is correct, but I've added clarification about this.